# Sum Decimal data type SwiftUI CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm having a problem on sum the filtered data using return method from "amount" attribute which have Decimal data type. The error msg like this and have a suggestion to Insert ' as! Decimal'  behind the amount but it doesn't help

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSDecimalNumber?' to expected argument type 'Decimal'

Here's my code

```
@FetchRequest(
     entity: ExpenseLog.entity(),
     sortDescriptors: [
      NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ExpenseLog.amount, ascending: false)
     ]
     ,predicate: NSPredicate(format: "(date => %@) AND (date <= %@)", DateHelper.startOfDay(day: NSDate()), DateHelper.endOfDay(day: NSDate()))
 )
 private var fetchSumDaily: FetchedResults<ExpenseLog>

var sumHarian: Decimal {
    fetchSumDaily.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.amount}
}
```

And here's my entities
[ExpenseLog Entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mBQW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your amount property is optional which you need to take into consideration. You should implement `reduce` like this

```
let sum = fetchSumDaily.reduce(Decimal(0.0)) {
    if let amount = $1.amount as Decimal? {
        return $0 + amount
    }

    return $0
}
```

Comment: I see, but there's still error msg like this when i implement it: 'Cannot use instance member 'fetchSumDaily' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available' Any idea?

Comment: That's a completely different issue and something you should be able to google yourself but in short, you can't use a variable that might not be initialised in the definition of another variable. Maybe turn it into a function instead.